# Properly answering keytool prompts?

Tags: android, keystore, keytool, signing

When I generate a private key (for signing apps) using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myappname.keystore -alias myappname -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

... I get asked a series of questions by keytool:

```
What is your first and last name?
What is the name of your organizational unit?
What is the name of your organization?
What is the name of your City or Locality?
What is the name of your State or Province?
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
```

1) What is the purpose of these questions?  Do they have any consequence?  Can I answer them with gibberish or will this cause me problems when releasing an app to, for example, the Android market?  I've googled this, and I am instructed to answer at least the first question with my hostname, but it is not clear why and if this is a strict rule or what the format should be exactly.

2) On a related note, if I create multiple apps, must I put all my private keys for them in one keystore or can i keep them in separate keystores (each with one private key for that app only)?  If I can keep them separate, again, how does that affect how I answer these questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. In most cases these information are **optional**. Just press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you do not want to provide any data. Do not put garbage
2. Depends what you like. You definitely should have **separate** certificate per application, but you can store all of them in either single keystore or multiple keystores. It does not matter from technical standpoint

Comment: Thanks. This is asked purely from a technical standpoint.  I take it you mean putting garbage is bad practice, but of no consequence.  I still am curious how this information is used, where it is exposed, etc.  Since you say 'most cases', maybe it depends on the application or distribution channel, and so it *could* be used in some verification step, but is not usually used.

Comment: These information become part of the certificate issued with the tool. As these are optional and just for informational purposes it makes no difference if you skip them or provide some valid data. It's complately up to you if you want people to see some more human - friendly data than certificate hash. I use some of them whenever I create new certifate for new app of mine.